# IE9 Main Menu initially disabled

Tags: internet-explorer-9

When I open IE9, the main menu is initially disabled. It is only enabled when I open a dialog, open developers tools, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clairify what you mean by 'main menu'?

Comment: File..Edit..View..Favorites, etc...

Comment: @MB34: Open **gpedit.msc** from the Run dialog and look under `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Browser menus`. Are any of [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S3eug.png) options enabled?

Comment: Nothing is enabled. The only option in that section is "Turn Off print Menu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour in Internet Explorer 9 and above. You can enable it by right clicking in the empty space at the top of the window and then clicking 'Menu bar'.

Or, if you just want it temporarily, you can just press the `Alt` key on your keyboard.

Comment: So it is default for the main menu to be disabled when you open the program, that is a load of BS. Pressing Alt key did not work.

Comment: @MB34 - I just tried.  It works in both IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me and now it come up enabled. I'll try it again tomorrow.

Comment: @MB34 worked fine for me, running IE9. Pressing ALT will only bring it up temporarily, then you need to click on View > Toolbars > Menu Bar to have it always display.

Comment: IT DOES display, it is disabled, meaning I can't select any items.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you meant the menu wasn't displayed. You could try reseting all the Internet Explorer settings back to default. You can do this by going into 'Internet Options', selecting the 'Advanced' tab and then clicking the 'Reset' button down the bottom of the window.

Comment: Looks like it is on some kind of timer. It enabled itself after around 45 seconds or so.